# Cumulative loan data with dates for a given firm in SAS

Tags: date, sas, left-join, accumulate

I'm working with a dataset dealscan and attempting to combine the tranche_amount for a given firm, subject to active date and maturity date, so I have a sum of total over a given period.

I have used left join

proc sql;

create table loancumulative  as
select a.startdate, sum(a.tranche_amount) as tranche_amount
from dealscan as a left join dealscan as b
on a.startdate >= b.startdate and a.startdate < b.enddate
group by a.startdate
order by a.startdate;

quit;

However need to also add by companyid, as I am running this across multiple firms .

Any comments?

Regards,

Seb

I added the perm_id as the company identifier in the tranche_amount some issues here?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to GROUP BY Syntax, all fields included in the select must be present in the group by clause except for the aggregated fields.

For example: SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country FROM Customers GROUP BY Country;

In your case, I think your query should be:

```
create table loancumulative as 
 select a.startdate, a.perm_id
      , sum(a.tranche_amount) as tranche_amount 
 from dealscan as a 
 left join dealscan as b 
 on a.startdate >= b.startdate and a.startdate < b.enddate 
 group by a.startdate, a.perm_id 
 order by a.startdate, a.perm_id
;
```

Comment: Thank You Samuel,  I Appreciate your feedback. I am only filtering by 1 category perm_id. But understand your point.

Comment: Great I could help.